# Neo4j grass file: how to BOLD a caption

Tags: neo4j

I would like to make a Neo4j caption bold.

In this grass file entry, how do I make the caption lettering bold?

```
node.probe {
  defaultCaption: "<id>";
  caption: "{name}";
  color: #F16667;
  border-color: #eb2728;
  text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 18px
 diameter: 160px;
}
```

Is it possible and, if so, tell me how.